# Obtain Trace(AAA) without calculating AAA

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace

Heyy ,please can anyone help me to obtain Trace(AAA) without calculating AAA matrix.
Best,[image]

Comment: Can you use that the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The matrices are idempotent, so $A^k=A\;$ for $k\ge 1$